# Why is there no tooltip property for raised and flat buttons?

Tags: material-ui

I often need the tooltip property to explain why a button is disabled, any reason why there is no support for that?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly for the same reason other features we'd like to include are currently unsupported.

Material-UI is developed almost exclusively by volunteers, and community contributors on their own time, so we have to pick and choose what to focus on.

We have talked about exposing `Tooltip` as a documented public component, but that will take work to clean up and document the API, and test it for use outside Material-UI components. At that point you'll be able to add a tooltip to a Button or anything else.

It's unlikely this will happen prior to the styles re-write that is targeted for the next breaking release, or the patch releases that will almost inevitably follow that major overhaul.

Comment: Ok, I don't need it as an external component, just as a property of existing buttons. I've been using the component undocumented. If I want to add the functionality. which release can I target my pull request?

Comment: If at some point we are going to make tooltip a composable component, then adding it to button now will be wasted effort. If you are successfully using the tooltip already, then I suggest you continue to do so until the Tooltip is officially available. Just be aware that the API is likely to change in a future release.

Comment: the use case I have is that I'm using tabs, in some states, I need to prevent tab changes, so i'm setting the disabled prop which propagates to the internal enhanced button, this works great, however I can't add a tooltip to the tab button, this would have been possible if enhanced button had a tooltip property, that's why I want to add it. as a separate component it wouldn't do much good for me.